# Xcode : Missing icons for iOS apps in Organizer's archives

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, organizer

If I choose "build and archive" from XCode, the Organizer is launched and I can see a list of my archived applications. I have 4 different applications (with several archives each), but the icon that's displayed in Organizer for one of the apps is missing -- there is a question mark icon instead. The app does have an associated icon and it validates and submits to the app store without any issues.

Why isn't Organizer picking up the icon correctly and how do I fix it?

Comment: 2012 revival of the same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800761/xcode-4-3-missing-icons-for-ios-apps-in-organizers-archives

Comment: The selected answer here worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10601484/why-xcode-4-3-2-shows-white-icon-when-archived

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not a bug, I think you need to have at least one for Iphone and a bigger one for ipad (although my app is only designed for iphone...). I replaced the "icon file" key with "icon files" in the plist file and put one 52x52, one 72x72 and also one 114x114.

Comment: More than one icon file is not required. I have several iPad apps that only have one icon specified in the plist by the CFBundleIconFile key and their icons show up fine in organizer.

Comment: In XCode 4.3.2, my plist file has three entries "Icon file", "Icon files", and "Icon files (iOS 5)".  Since I'm building a universal app (iPhone/iPad/iPodTouch) and targeting iOS 4.3 from the iOS 5.1 SDK (latest stable), it's no surprise I'm getting a few icon warnings with all these different configurations!  Archive Build is the only build that complains so far!

Comment: I've identified the two problems keeping my Archive Build from succeeding.  For whatever reason, the Archive build found lower-cased versions of icons "icon.png" instead of "Icon.png" in a 3rd-party library template.  My solution is to "git rm" those files.  I also got a warning for including landscape launch images when that mode is disabled for now because of a CSS rendering issue...Hopefully just portrait mode is OK with Apple...

Comment: I found a third build problem, the build step "Copy Bundle Resources" can interfere with your icons!  My project uses PhoneGap/Cordova, and it added a default copy step that stomps all over my icons and breaks the build even when I delete theirs!  Solution: Remove the extra copy build step.

Comment: do I have to fix it? or it's just a thing on the organiser and all will be fine on store and devices?

Comment: My icon file field in plist is empty nothing under it! I am using Xcode 5 and I used assets catalog to add icon.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a bug. I see the same for all my apps that I Build & Archive.

Comment: Yeah I think it's a bug, at least in Xcode 4.  Having the Icon Files in info.plist with the corresponding icon resolutions doesn't help.  One of my apps that did show an icon in the Xcode 3.x organizer now has no icon in Xcode 4.

Answer (score 2):

Include in the info.plist for the key "Icon File" the value "Icon.png".
Do not forget to also include the image in the container.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, and I solved it by adding a "Icon file" in info.plist, and adding a "Icon files" after "Icon file", and the icon is fine in organizer.  I think that might a parsing sequence problem.

Answer (score 1):

Those of you that have upgraded to Xcode 4.3 and are having problems with the Application Icons showing up in the Organizer Window under Archives, look at this posting which includes a solution:

[Xcode 4.3 : missing icons for iOS apps in Organizer's archives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800761/xcode-4-3-missing-icons-for-ios-apps-in-organizers-archives)

Answer (score 0):

When I had a missing icon in the organizer, I appended

.icns

to the Icon file name in the Info.plist file.

Comment: I haven't found anything in the documentation to support even attempting this.

Answer (score 0):

For XCode 4.2 :

Patrick Burleson's answer is correct, and worked for me.  However, the icon that showed up in the organizer was still fuzzy/low-resolution after doing that.  I fixed this by putting Icon@2x.png in the "Item 0" slot of 'Icon Files', instead of putting Icon.png there as I had before.  No idea why I should need to do that, but in any case, if someone else has that issue, that may be the way to fix it.