# Ios app icon not shown and name missing why?

Tags: ios

I am having some problems with icon & name of my app and although I finished my app because of these I cant publish it.Its not a code related problem and  because of that I asked it on diffrent forums but none gave me right answer so as a last hope I decided to ask it here.

1)I managed to put 57x57 px png icon for my app and when I put the it on my phone it's oke but in itunes my app is shown without a icon.I thought that putting 114x144 px icon should solve this problem but I cant do it.When I rightclick and select the "select-file" in 57x57 I can put any png there but its not avalible on 114x114 when I rightclick there is no "selectfile" option and other options aswell.Also same problem happens in launch images.

Is it the reason of no icon showing problem in my itunes or my app can work without it?

In some pages I saw people talking about putting all png files in root with a info file and made it automaticly but I couldt find any tutorial about it.

2)My second problem is about the name.My project name is kdd2 but of course its not my app name kdd2 was a simple name I gave it a month ago.When I disturbute my app I change the name and save it to my desktop.In desktop its shown with the name I wrote it but when I put it in ıtunes or iPhone its name again changes to kdd2 how can I solve it ?

Please help me solve these problems I just cant find any answer around thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To change the app name:**

-Click your project in the navigator in Xcode.

-Go to "Build Settings" tab.

-Change "Product Name" under "Packaging'.

**To set the icon:**

You must right lick the **border** then "Select File". Do not right click "No image specified".

Comment: The name problem is solved also I managed to add 114px icon aswell but still app has no icon in iTunes why ?

Comment: I do not know why you cannot see the icons in iTunes. Have you tried(iTunes->Preferences->general settings->show icons)?

Comment: of course I can see all other icosn just mine is not there.I searched more about this project and find out that after Xcode 4.3 these problems happen many users there are some solutions for it to

here is the whole discussion

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800761/xcode-4-3-missing-icons-for-ios-apps-in-organizers-archives

Comment: Did that solve your problem? You can set icon in the app-info.plist file as well.