# validation issue after adding "Missing recommended icon files "to Info.plist

Tags: ios

After I upload a new version of my app  I got a mail from iTunes Store:

> Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format.
>
> Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '76x76' pixels, in .png format.
>
> Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '152x152' pixels, in .png format.
> "

I added to my application and to Info.plist : icon-76, icon-76@2x , icon_60, icon_60@2x , but now I can't pass validation. I got an error:

> Icon specified in the Info.plist not found under the top level app wrapper.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736954/missing-recommended-icon-file-the-bundle-does-not-contain-an-app-icon-for-ipho)

Comment: I added missing icon files <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
   <array>
    <string>icon_57.png</string>
    <string>icon_72.png</string>
    <string>icon_57@2x .png</string>
    <string>icon_72@2x .png</string>
    <string>icon_60.png</string>
    <string>icon_76.png</string>
    <string>icon_60@2x.png</string>
    <string>icon_76@2x.png</string>
   </array>                                    but now my problem that I have a validation error " "Icon specified in the Info.plist not found under the top level app wrapper". "

Comment: icon.png(57*57) it's retina icon@2x.png(114*114) and it's icon-120.png(120 * 120 it should be high-resolution) andalso add iTunesArtwork in to bundle

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800761/xcode-4-3-missing-icons-for-ios-apps-in-organizers-archives?rq=1 
May help this link

Comment: I was prompted to migrate the icons to its own assets folder.  I said yes and the problem disappeared.

Comment: I was mistaken on icon file name. The name of icon file is "Icon_60.png" .... not "icon_60.png".  I changed it and the problem got resolved. Shame on me, what a stupid mistake! Thanks to @python . His link helped me to find a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

For older devices, save your 57x57 icon as Icon_iPhone.png. For the iPhone 4, save your 114x114 icon as Icon_iPhone@2x.png. The image resolution doesn't matter at all; only the pixel dimensions matter.

For iPad Save your 72x72 icon as Icon_iPad.png and 144x144 icon as Icon_ iPad.png@2x.png

Once crass check the your app icons sizes

Better way

Select XCode.Project -> Summery -> App Icons - >

Just Drag and Drop the images (icons) in App Icons Boxes . It will not show any Yellow mark Thread your icons perfectly set other wise sizes miss match . (In this way no need to add icon file in plist)

Comment: What about new required icon files 76*76px, 152*152px and 120*120 px?

Comment: I have a problem with new icon files not old ones  warning: Icon specified in the Info.plist not found under the top level app wrapper: icon_60.png (-19007)Unable to validate your application. - (null)warning: Icon specified in the Info.plist not found under the top level app wrapper: icon_76.png (-19007)Unable to validate your application.warning: Icon specified in the Info.plist not found under the top level app wrapper: icon_60@2x.png (-19007)Unable to validate your application.warning: Icon specified in the Info.plist not found under the top level app wrapper: icon_76@2x.png (-19007)

Answer (score 0):

See multiple answers here: [Icon specified in info.plist not found under the top level app wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165664/icon-specified-in-info-plist-not-found-under-the-top-level-app-wrapper)

For me the fix was to add the files to the Build Phases, Copy Bundle Resources section of the project settings.